# jmeter csv data set config issue: Could not read file header line for file

Tags: jmeter

Im trying to extract data from a csv file to use in a POST request but i get the below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file v2summaryreport
```

the v2summaryreport is saved from another threads summary report and i want to use that csv for a new set of results that will be posted out.

[image: csv config]

error message

```
020-09-23 16:26:14,826 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2020-09-23 16:26:14,831 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 3-1
2020-09-23 16:26:14,832 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: v2summaryreport
2020-09-23 16:26:14,832 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file v2summaryreport
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:283) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:135) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:251) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_261]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File v2summaryreport must exist and be readable
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:424) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:340) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:324) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:272) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
```

Any help with this would be appreciated

Comment: Have you solved your issue? We are facing the same error message, but with a .csv file that is supplied via params. The file is there, and jmeter detects it in the beginning. But when loading we get the cryptic error above. Was there anything you did to fix your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> File v2summaryreport must exist and be readable

It means that JMeter cannot find the CSV file under the given location

You need to supply either relative or full path the the file (in the majority of cases along with the extension) so I think it should be something like `v2summaryreport.txt` or `v2summaryreport.jtl`

Also pay attention to [Execution Order of JMeter test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) as there might be a chance that being a [Configuration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) CSV Data Set Config is executed **before** everything else so the file with the results isn't there yet.

Working with dynamic CSV files is not very supported use case, you might want to consider migrating to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead, see [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) article for example implementation.

Comment: I tried csv read with the below:
${__CSVRead(v2summaryreport.csv,1)}

But i get this error:
2020-09-24 09:32:18,145 WARN o.a.j.f.CSVRead: Thread Group 3-1 - invalid column number: 1 at row 0 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the location you provided is not correct to extract CSV file. And you have to make sure that data can be properly extracted from that CSV file before start running the script.

An example is attached here.

[image]

Comment: Ive tried this with an explicit path but i game the same issue. The path i used was:

C:\Users\sfry\OneDrive\Documents\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\v2summaryreport.csv

The error i get is 

2020-09-24 09:12:46,574 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: C:\Users\sfry\OneDrive\Documents\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\v2summaryreport.csv
2020-09-24 09:12:46,574 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file C:\Users\sfry\OneDrive\Documents\jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\v2summaryreport.csv

Comment: Does Top line of CSV includes the column name?

Comment: yep, all column names are in the csv

Comment: Can you remove them and test them again? Sometimes this happens because those column names are not fitting to the type of the rest of the CSV.

Comment: and make sure that there are no spaces between data in the CSV files and only the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are uploading CSV file instead of xlsx. I have faced same problem but later I got to know that I was uploading .xlsx file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUdLl.png)